# Is it possible to start a docker container with some env variables from the docker API

Tags: docker

I'm using docker API to manage my containers from a front-end application and I would like to know if it was possible to use /container/{id}/start with some environnement variables, i can't find it in the official doc.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only specify environment variables when [creating a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerCreate).  Starting it just starts the main process in the container that already exists with its existing settings; the [“start” API call](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerStart) has almost no options beyond the container ID.  If you’ve stopped a container and want to restart it with different options, you need to delete and recreate it.